# Stack vs stuck in the StackExchange

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I am not sure where to ask the question. Will be grateful if someone would move it to the right site.

Right now you can see StackExchange in the left upper corner. Let us google the meaning of the stack [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stack_1?q=stack):

> - a pile of something, usually neatly arranged
> - (computing) a way of storing information in a computer in which the most recently stored item is the first to be retrieved (= found or got back)

And let us google the meaning of stuck [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stuck?q=stuck):

> - unable to move or to be moved
> - in an unpleasant situation or place that you cannot escape from

Given those two definitions it seems naturally to ask: Why do we have StackExchange instead of StuckExchange?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-do-the-names-of-the-stack-overflow-trilogy-sites-come-from

Comment: Why not call it *StuckOverflow?* Apparently, here in London we're currently battling with a [*giant stuck "**underflow**".*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-41238272)

Comment: I copied what I thought were the relevant definitions into the question so others don't have to follow the links. Please feel free to re-edit if I got the wrong bits. (However, reading the entire definition pages still didn't help me understand what you're asking.)

Comment: I don't get the close reason; the question seems clear enough.

Comment: @Casey: The original site was called "Stack Overflow", not "Stuck Overflow". Bringing up the definition of "stuck" seems like a *non sequitur*: I don't see what's natural about the question posed in the last sentence of this post. That said, part of the reason I close-voted was also for lack of research: if someone wants to ask about why something was named something, I think it makes sense for that person to first research the actual history of the name rather than just look up the definitions of some words in the name

Comment: @sumelic The question is based on a misapprehension (that "Stack" was some fanciful spelling of "Stuck," maybe, or maybe that they're homophones), but the "unclear what you're asking" close seems weird to me because... what he's asking is completely clear; it's just odd.  Maybe it'd make more sense on the English language learners site instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Stack Exchange is based on the first created site, Stack Overflow

By that, I mean that the **software** of Stack Exchange was originally based on that of the (already existing) Stack Overflow.

[As per the Wikipedia page on Stack Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange):

> In **2008**, Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky created **Stack Overflow**, a question-and-answer Web site for computer programming questions, which they described as an alternative to the programmer forum Experts-Exchange. In 2009, they started additional sites based on the Stack Overflow model: Server Fault for questions related to system administration and Super User for questions from computer "power users".
>
> In **September 2009**, Spolsky's company, Fog Creek Software, released a beta version of the **Stack Exchange** 1.0 platform as a way for third parties to create their own communities **based on the software behind Stack Overflow**, with monthly fees. This white label service was not successful, with few customers and slowly growing communities.
>
> In **May 2010**, Stack Overflow (as its own new company) raised US$6 million in venture capital from Union Square Ventures and other investors, and it switched its focus to developing new sites for answering questions on specific subjects, **Stack Exchange 2.0**.

As you can see, Stack Overflow existed before the more generalized Stack Exchange platform was presented. Though not explicitly mentioned in the article, it seems fair to assume that the massive success of Stack Overflow in the developers community has inspired its creators to also open up similar sites that focus on different topics, which is what we now refer to as "Stack Exchange".

In other words, the "Stack" in "**Stack** Exchange" is a reference to the "Stack" in "**Stack** Overflow".

Comment: I guess that 'stack exchange' is a reference to 'stock exchange' ( a pun/ word play)?

Comment: @Stefan: That would merit a separate answer, as it contradicts the premise of my answer. I'm not saying you're definitely wrong, but you're suggesting a completely different explanation.

Comment: I don't think there is a contradiction. Your answer is probably right. My comment is just a hypothesis for the inspiration for that name, as I often find this kind of puns used when naming things related to software. (Eg. Java and JavaBeans, Espresso compiler, etc. - not related to the above, but same kind of "humor"). Anyway, if you find my comment just noise, I will delete this and the other comment.